# Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message ""

Tags: laravel, email, gmail, swiftmailer

I was sending myself error emails from a Gmail account and it was working.

Suddenly the emails crash and I get

> Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message "".

I'm not sure why this is happening I'm sending around 80 emails.

This is my code:

```php
$backup = Mail::getSwiftMailer();

// Setup your gmail mailer
$transport = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance($email_config['host'], $email_config['port'], $email_config['security']);
$transport->setUsername($email_config['from_email']);
$transport->setPassword($email_config['from_email_password']);
// Any other mailer configuration stuff needed...
$gmail = new \Swift_Mailer($transport);

// Set the mailer as gmail
Mail::setSwiftMailer($gmail);


$cc = $email_config["cc"];
$to_email = $email_config["to"];

\Log::info("mail 1");
\Log::info($to_email);
// Send your message
\Mail::send('emails.error_log', ['body' => $body], function ($message) use ($from_email, $to_email, $subject, $cc) {
    $message->from($from_email);
    $message->to($to_email);
    $message->cc($cc);
    $message->subject($subject);
});
\Log::info("mail 2");

// Restore your original mailer
Mail::setSwiftMailer($backup);
```

Comment: Maybe you have reached max emails per day for gmail? I think it's around 100 per day but I could be completely wrong about this. Try ```php artisan config:cache``` maybe it does some magic.

Comment: @DinoNumić When i rerun my cron emails get sent again and then they crash so it cant be that. I had already tried that command and still got the error.

Comment: so some of them still send but it fails sending all of them? can you pinpoint an exact mail on which it fails, that would help.

Comment: I am having a similar problem. php-fpm can send the email with the exact same settings, but php-cli fails like yours. any ideas about what this can be?